# Can't Get Table Column Widths to be Equal in Wordpress.com

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress.com

I have created a table on my page through Wordpress.com (the free version). I do not have access to the css, but I can put a table on the page. However, even though I have set the column widths equally, they do not show up that way. The first column is wider than the other.

Am I using the code improperly? If so, how should it be written?

```
<table width="98%">
<col width="49">
<col width="49">
<tr>
<th>Bhakti Siddhanta</th>
<th>Note</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>The 10 Divisions of the Srimad Bhagavatam</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

98% refers to the width of the container the table is in. It is a dynamic size. Your table will size to 98% of whatever its sitting in, and the first column will be 49 pixels wide. The second column will be stuck with whatever is left.

Try col width = "50%" for both columns